# Positive class in keras classification report has a precision of zero

Tags: python, validation, keras

I'm performing binary classification on a Kaggle dataset that is known to be quite balanced and it has a shape of (129880,22).

My precision on the negative class is very low and it's zero on the positive class. roc-auc = 0.9934% and the true positives and true negatives are in line with the data.

Since I'm performing binary classification with 22 inputs, do I have too many Dense layers? I experimented manually and with BayesSearchCV, but not very familiar with the api.

```
def get_model():
  return keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(22, input_dim=22, activation=tf.nn.relu, name = "Dense_1"),
    keras.layers.Dense(22, activation=tf.nn.relu, name = "Dense_2"),
    keras.layers.Dense(11, activation=tf.nn.relu, name = "Dense_3"),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid, name = "sigmoid")
  ])

keras_model = get_model()
keras_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01), 
              loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy, 
              metrics=["accuracy"]
              )
keras_model.summary()

keras_model.fit(scaled_X_train, y_train, steps_per_epoch=5, epochs=100, callbacks = earlystopping)
keras_model.evaluate(scaled_X_test, y_test, batch_size=10)

y_pred = (keras_model.predict(scaled_X_test) > 0.5)
y_predict_label = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
report = classification_report(y_test.flatten(), y_pred.flatten())



              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.57      1.00      0.72     14690
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00     11286

    accuracy                           0.57     25976
   macro avg       0.28      0.50      0.36     25976
weighted avg       0.32      0.57      0.41     25976
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: the output of the sigmoid is a number between 0 and 1, not the class label itself, so maybe apply a `>0.5` operator to it to make it binary before passing it to classification_report.

Comment: Please note that interpreting data is not a programming problem and thus off-topic in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks. But when I change that line I get `'Series' object has no attribute 'flatten'`. Because `y_test` is a pandas.core.series.Series

Comment: I got it. I changed it to `y_test.values.flatten()` Because flatten is a method of np.array not of pd.Series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason why you are getting low precision in the classification_report is because `y_pred` is the correct input to classification_report instead of `y_predict_label` (because this is a binary classification problem), so the last line should look as follows.

```py
report = classification_report(y_test.flatten(), y_pred.flatten())
```

as for the validation plot, it is not uncommon for it to be noisy, this is because of the 'noise' in the training process (which includes quantization noise due to training on a subset of the data).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ahmed-aek for giving me a clue to flatten `y_test` because of the dimensions mismatch.

I had to add `values` in the line `y_test.values.flatten()` because flatten is a method of np.array not of pd.Series.

Now the classification report looks copacetic.

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.95      0.98      0.96     14690
           1       0.97      0.93      0.95     11286

    accuracy                           0.96     25976
   macro avg       0.96      0.95      0.96     25976
weighted avg       0.96      0.96      0.96     25976
```